# Getting error while Add to Cart programmatically with custom options

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to Add Products to Cart with respect to customer (programmatically) but getting error "Invalid request for adding product to quote". I have both Simple products (with custom options) and configurable products. Below is my code. Please help. Many thanks in advance.

```
public function addtocartAction(){
try {
    $cusId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cusId');
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($cusId);
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $quoteId = $quote->getId();
    //$products = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products');
    $products = json_decode('[{"proId": "906","proQty": "1", "options":{"17":"wq","16":"18"}}]');

    foreach($products as $product) {
        /*if (!$product->getId()) {
            throw new Exception();
        }*/
        foreach ($product->options as $optKey => $optValue) {
            $optAll[$optKey] = $optValue;
        }

        $mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->proId);
        $params = array(
            'product' => $product->proId,
            'qty'     => $product->proQty,
            'options' => $optAll
        );
        echo "<pre />"; print_r($params);
        $quote->addProduct($mainProduct, $params);
        $quote->setIsActive(1);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }
    $rslt['success'] = '1';
    $rslt['message'] = 'Product has been succefully added to cart';
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $rslt['success'] = '0';
    $rslt['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
print_r(json_encode($rslt));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try using **cart** instead of **quote**.
This works for me:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->proId);
$params = array(
        'product' => $product->proId,
        'qty'     => $product->proQty,
        'options' => $optAll
);
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($mainProduct, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This code working only for simple products. How can I make it work for configurable products as well? when I am trying to do for configurable its showing error "Please specify the product's option(s)."

Comment: You have to use the **super_attribute** in options, providing attribute and their values. For example: 
`$params = array(
        'product' => $product->proId,
        'super_attribute' => array(
            132 => 3, 
            133 => 8
        ),
        'qty' => $product->proQty,
    );`  133,132 are attribute_ids and 3,8 are attribute values.